# Laravel 5 Get DB Prefix

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

In Laravel 4 I could do this to get the table prefix:

```
$prefix = DB::getTablePrefix();
```

What's the equivalent in L5?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work like that still.

Comment: Yes, `Class 'App\DB' not found`

Comment: Make sure that you are referencing facades in the base namespace. Try `\DB::getTablePrefix();`. You'll probably have `namespace App` at the top of your file and that means you're no longer running in the base namespace. I can give you an answer describing how to follow through the definition of the facade and how I figure the method should still work if you're interested.

Comment: That worked! I added `User \DB as DB;` before I instantiate my model. Then when I call `$prefix = DB::getTablePrefix();` it works great. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, please post that as an answer and I'll select it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue was not that the method was not accessible from the facade, but rather the facade was not being called correctly in the base namespace.

Using `\DB::getTablePrefix()` or placing `use \DB as DB` at the top of the document solves the problem.

As requested, I will describe the steps I took to ensure the method was still accessible through the facade:

1. **Check the facade is still there**. The facades are registered in
   the `config/app.php` file and refer to a PSR-4 namespace of the
   class behind the facade
2. **Check what class the facade points at**. This is a little more tricky and requires a little bit of intelligent guesswork. First, I accessed the facade definition using the PSR-4 class name from step 1. That points to [this file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/DB.php) in the Laravel source. This simply sets the facade to point to an object in the "[Service Container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container)" named "db"

   In order to find what registers this service, I had to guess the service provider which is registered in the `config/app.php` file. There's a service called `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider` which is the only thing I saw related to database, so I guessed that. This is also a PSR-4 class name so you can find the file pretty easily in the Laravel source [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseServiceProvider.php)

   I can see in this service provider that "db" is registered as a `DatabaseManager`.
3. **Investigate the service that the facade is fronting**. `DatabaseManager` is not specifically namespaced in the service provider and therefore must exist in the same namespace, which means it'll be in the same folder in the source. I opened up the `DatabaseManager` and looked for the method `getTablePrefix`. I didn't find it, but I did find a `__call` magic method that will [proxy to another object](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php#L302) accessed with `$this->connection()`.

   Looking at the `connection` method, I can see from the PHPdoc block on this method that it returns a `\Illuminate\Database\Connection` which is a PSR-4 class name (again). It's also in the same namespace as the `DatabaseManager` I'm looking at. I opened [this file](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L1095) and found the method you're looking for.

It might seem like a bit of effort to find if the facade still provides access to a method, but using a good IDE (PHPStorm in my case) and knowing the basics about it (which I hopefully described here) means you can look these things up in less than a minute.

One of the major advantages of Laravel 5 (and PSR-4) is that all the class names and namespaces should resemble the file system so everything should be pretty intuitive.

Comment: `use \DB as DB` was the key for me. Thanks!

Comment: You can `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` (instead of `use DB;` or `use \DB as DB`), so you get auto completion for the methods available in the facade. This was included in more recent versions of Laravel, after this answer was written.